# How to assign a constant in x86 Assembly AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, intel

I've searched all over the internet and I can't find the equivalent of the following in AT&T syntax. How is this done in INTEL?

```
 %assign SYS_EXIT 1
 %assign SYS_WRITE 4
 %assign SYS_READ 3
 %assign SYS_OPEN 5
 %assign SYS_CLOSE 6
 %assign SYS_CREATE 8
```

Using AS - the portable GNU assembler.

Comment: `%assign` is a directive of your assembler. Thus you should mention what assembler you are using. Also, the intel vs at&t syntax business usually applies to the instructions only, not to the directives. As such, it should work the same, with the possible minor change of adding a `$` prefix when using at&t to indicate an immediate.

Comment: AS - the portable GNU assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that would be something like

```
SYS_EXIT EQU 1
SYS_WRITE EQU 4
...
```

Comment: Okay, defined in the .data section I am assuming. I wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: @user2499298 : Actually, the section does not matter. `EQU` constants are not inserted into the final object file in any section. They are only used internally by the assembler.

Comment: symbol equ x means to equate the symbol to that value AT ASSEMBLY TIME. It has no effect at all on the generated code unless you use that symbol elsewhere.